# Condicional If en base a opción selecionada en Select

Tags: javascript, html

Me preguntaba como se puede hacer una condicional if en base a opción selecionada en un select, tengo el siguiente fragmento de código, dentro de la concional coloque gestion.options[gestion.selectedIndex].text &&, pero no se como hacer que tome en cuenta la option seleccionada, necestio que si se selecciona "Alta" se cumpla una condiciona y si se selecciona "Baja" se cumpla otra función, pero que la condicional tome también en cuenta la demas sentencia por eso el && doble... ¿Podrían ayudarme? (Si le falta algo al codigo diganme y lo anexo)

```
 <html>
 <section class="col-4">
    <select id="selectTab2Gestion" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 100%; height: 
    37.5px; font-size: 14px;">
       <option value="opción" selected = "selected" disabled>Selecciona una opción...</option>
       <option value="alta">Alta</option>
       <option value="baja">Baja</option>
     </select>
  </section>
 </html>
 <script>
   /*Tomar el valor del Select Gestión > Servicios Menu Tab*/
   var gestion = document.getElementById("selectTab2Gestion");
   var servicioGestion = gestion.options[gestion.selectedIndex].text;       

   if (gestion.options[gestion.selectedIndex].text && document.getElementById('radioCheckNoServicios').checked && textoNull == ''){
    var comentario = "Cuenta: " + cuenta + "\n\Comunica: "+ comunica + "\n\Nombre: " + persona + "\n\Hora: " + hora +  "\n\Ejecutivo: " + ejecutivo + "\n\Área Ejecutiva: " + areaEjecutiva 
    + "\n\Problema: " + comunica + " " + persona + " solicita " + servicioGestion + " de servicio " +  servicioAB + ".";
    + "\n\Solucion: Se corrobora Clave de Elector " + claveElector + " correctamente se procede con solicitud de " + comunica + " " +  titular + ", se genera " + servicioGestion + " de " + servicioAB 
    + " con costo de " + precioServicio + " se indica a titular que no se generara cobro del servicio " + servicioAB + " en la siguiente facturacion."
    document.getElementById("textareaComentarioIncidencia").innerHTML = comentario;       
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Hola BetaM los radiobuttons solo son parte del condicional, puedes omitirlos no son necesarios, no hay error necesito que el if se cumpla si se selecciona una option, if se selecciona alta se cumpla la condicion else if selecciona baja se cumpla otra función, solo me falto agrega el else...

Comment: No entiendo cual es resultado que esperas pero puedes obtener el valor seleccionado agregandole onchange al select.

Comment: Ange Reyna, es facil (solo decirlo hahaha) solo necesito que si se selecciona alta se cumpla una condicion si se selecciona baja se cumpla otra, ejemplo si se selecciona alta muestre algun alert si se seleccione baja se recargue la página...

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que tienes que hacer es determinar cuando quieres recuperar el valor del `<option>` seleccionado. Podrías hacerlo cuando el valor del `<select>` cambia, para ello tendrías que asignarle al `<select>` un evento `change` (como en el ejemplo de mi respuesta), también podríar obtener su valor en cualquier otro momento.

En el ejemplo que pongo a continuación se asigna un evento `change` al `<select>` para que cuando su valor cambie se pueda capturar y dependiendo de este hacer una cosa u otra.

```js
const selectElement = document.querySelector('#selectTab2Gestion');

selectElement.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
   const seleccionado = event.target.value;
   
   if (seleccionado === 'alta') {
      console.log('Se ha elegido alta');
   }
   else if (seleccionado === 'baja') {
      console.log('Se ha elegido baja');
   }
});
```

```html
<select id="selectTab2Gestion" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="width: 100%; height: 
    37.5px; font-size: 14px;">
   <option value="opción" selected = "selected" disabled>Selecciona una opción...</option>
   <option value="alta">Alta</option>
   <option value="baja">Baja</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: Es algo como lo que neccesito phpMyGuel, pero sin embargo no me funciona si lo incrustro en el archivo javascript, solo si lo incrustro en el html... ¿Cómo corrigo eso?